# Undefined symbols when using C header-only implementation in C++ file

Tags: c++, c

Is there a rule I'm unaware of regarding how a C header-only file, which contains actual implementations, gets linked into C++?

I have a header-only C file that includes full definitions of several functions. When I include this file in a `.cpp` file, and then compile, the linker reports that several of the functions named in that file are undefined.

The error looks like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "par_shapes_free_mesh(par_shapes_mesh_s*)", referenced from:
      App::testgeo() in App.o
```

The C file has this in it:

```
void par_shapes_free_mesh(par_shapes_mesh*); //forward declaration

void par_shapes_free_mesh(par_shapes_mesh* mesh)
{
    free(mesh->points);
    free(mesh->triangles);
    free(mesh->normals);
    free(mesh->tcoords);
    free(mesh);
}
```

Clearly, the function is in fact defined. I include this file at the top of my App.cpp and then use `par_shapes_free_mesh` but it produces this error. I'm confounded.

I tried the following trick but it made no difference:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

//and corresponding end brace
```

This had the interesting effect of providing the same error messages, but with an underscore in the name:

`"_par_shapes_free_mesh", referenced from:`

There is also this typedef in the file:

```
typedef struct par_shapes_mesh_s {
    float* points;
    int npoints;
    uint16_t* triangles;
    int ntriangles;
    float* normals;
    float* tcoords;
} par_shapes_mesh;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for the definitions to be included during compilation you need to add `#define PAR_SHAPES_IMPLEMENTATION` to your source file *before* including `par_shapes.h`.

```
#define PAR_SHAPES_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "par_shapes.h"
```

Comment: I assume you'd know this because you are familiar the C library in question? I never realized I'd need this, I'll try it.

Comment: Nope, never even heard of the library until now. But being a backup-dancer for Google and knowing amalgamations can require explicit inclusion of definitions it wasn't too difficult to figure out.

Comment: well, thanks, you nailed it. and i learned something about C libraries